# conditioning, constant and independence

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares

I am reading Wooldrige's "Introductory Econometrics" and wondering about the assumptions on Linear Regression especially the conditioning assumptions:

1. $ E(u|X) = 0 $ and $ Var(u|X) = σ^2 $

If the conditioned value is a constant, does it mean that unconditioned $ E(u) $ and $ Var(u)$ are simply the same constant since they don't depend on the X condition?

2. If so, why would he need to go through the following: "Because $ Var(u|X) $ = $ E(u^2|X) $ - $[E(u|X)]^2$ and $ E(u|X) = 0 $ , $ E(u^2|X) = σ^2 $, which means $ σ^2 $ is also the unconditional expectation of $u^2$. Therefore, $σ^2 = E(u^2) = Var(u)$, because $E(u) = 0$. In other words, $σ^2$ is the unconditional variance of u."  Are the derivation necessary or I am missing something?
3. Does  $ E(u|X) = 0 $ mean X and u are uncorrelated, independent or neither?
4. Lastly, why not just assume $ E(u) = 0 $ and $ Var(u) = σ^2 $? These seem to go into proving unbiasedness of OLS estimator anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the unconditionals are the same **in this case** because of the law of total expectation and the law of total variance. $E[u] = E[E(u|X)] = 0$ and $\text{Var}(u) = \text{Var}[E(u|X)] + E[\text{Var}(u|X)] = \sigma^2$. The reasoning in bullet point (2) also works. Specifying the conditional moments is *more specific*.

Regarding $3$, iterating expectations and applying this assumption shows us the unconditional mean of $u$ is $0$, which in turn means the covariance between $X$ and $u$ is equal to $E[uX]$. Iterating expectations again gives us $\text{Cov}(u,X) = E[XE[u|X]] = 0$.

Regarding $4$, because it's less specific. For instance $u$ could have mean zero (i.e. $E[u] = 0$ but conditional mean not constantly zero. If you flip forward in the book there are probably some examples where the conditional variance of $u$ will explicitly depend on $X$.

Comment: Regarding 3 we have to specify that, yes, $E[u|X]=0$ do not "mean" uncorrelation, however it is implied.

Comment: thanks @markowitz your comment has inspired the most recent edit